# Type annotations for dynamic created class methods in class factory

Tags: python, mypy, typing

I'm working on a `Bundle` class with the intent to map function calls to multiple `Module` instances. As there will be multiple Modules, each having it's own Bundle subclass I created a class factory which performs the function mapping. Now I'm struggeling with type annotations and im wondering if it is even possible to get complete and correct type annotations for all cases.

Currently I have the following code:

```
from typing import (Any, Callable, Dict, Generic, Iterable,
                List, Type, TypeVar, cast)


_T = TypeVar('_T')


class Module():

    def __init__(self, name):
        print(" {}.__init__ ".format(self.__class__.__name__).center(80, '-'))
        self.name = name

    def meth1(self, param: int) -> float:
        print(" {}.meth1 ".format(self.__class__.__name__).center(80, '-'))
        return param * 1.5


class Bundle(Generic[_T]):

    _subs: List[_T]

    def __init__(self, subs: Iterable[_T]):
        self._subs = list(subs)

    def bundle_func(self) -> None:
        print(" {}.bundle_func ".format(self.__class__.__name__).center(80, '-'))


def wrap_func(func: Callable[..., _T]) -> Callable[..., List[_T]]:
    # Wrap function such that the original function is executed on
    # all self._subs and all the results returned as a list.
    def wrapper(self: Bundle, *args, **kwargs) -> List[_T]:
        results = []
        for sub in self._subs:
            results.append(getattr(sub, func.__name__)(*args, **kwargs))
        return results

    return wrapper


def create_bundle(mod: Type[_T]) -> Type[Bundle[_T]]:
    # Create a new bundle class by mapping / wrapping all functions of the
    # `mod` class to the bundle class. This is not a direct mapping, 
    # a single call to the bundle function should execute the function
    # on all `_subs` of the bundle (see wrap_func). 

    func_names = [name for name in dir(mod) if not name.startswith('_') and callable(getattr(mod, name))]

    namespace = dict()
    for func_name in func_names:
        namespace[func_name] = wrap_func(getattr(mod, func_name))

    cls = cast(Type[Bundle[_T]], type(mod.__name__ + 'Bundle', (Bundle, ), namespace))
    return cls


ModuleBundle = create_bundle(Module)

reveal_type(Bundle)                # Correct
reveal_type(Bundle.bundle_func)    # Correct

reveal_type(ModuleBundle)          # Correct
reveal_type(ModuleBundle.meth1)    # Not Correct: "..." has no attribute "meth1"

mb = ModuleBundle([Module('A'), Module('B')])
reveal_type(mb)                    # Correct
```

As shown in the last lines, most of the types work as expected. However, the dynamically added functions are not working and mypy can't find the methods:

```
bundle_test3.py:77: note: Revealed type is "def [_T] (subs: typing.Iterable[_T`1]) -> bundle_test3.Bundle[_T`1]"
bundle_test3.py:78: note: Revealed type is "def [_T] (self: bundle_test3.Bundle[_T`1])"
bundle_test3.py:80: note: Revealed type is "Type[bundle_test3.Bundle[bundle_test3.Module*]]"
bundle_test3.py:81: error: "Type[Bundle[Module]]" has no attribute "meth1"
bundle_test3.py:81: note: Revealed type is "Any"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Is there a way to annotate the class factory, or any other part of the code, such that the type annotations for functions mapped from the `Module` to the `Bundle` subclass are actually working?

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out which parts are actually relevant for the question and which are just unrelated leftovers. Can you try and reduce some of the code? Using consistent naming schemes (e.g. ``snake_case`` for functions) would also help. It looks like you want to create an [intersection type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_type) of ``Bundle`` and ``Module``, is that correct?

Comment: I switched the naming of `createBundle` -> `create_bundle`, but otherwise I don't see a way to further reduce the code and still have a working example. I think I want something like an intersection type as mentioned, but I'm not exactly shure.

Comment: Is `ModuleBundle` supposed to be (effectively) a subclass of both `Module` and `Bundle`? You can simply do that with `class ModuleBundle(Bundle, Module): pass`. I'm not sure what `create_bundle` is doing here.

Comment: `ModuleBundle` is supposed to be a subclass of `Bundle`, providing all methods of `Bundle` and `Module`. However, all methods copied over from `Module` should be run on all modules (`_subs`) of the bundle, so I would not say that this is a subclass of `Module` in OOP terms. I added comments in the code to clarify the intent.

Comment: I don't think that is possible to do without dependent types (aka impossible in the current Python ``typing``). Your code is not merely "mapping" functions from ``Module`` to ``Bundle``, it is creating new callables from any callables in any namespace; it is perfectly doable to *create a* callable from any callable and *map any* callable from any namespace, but not both at once.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi while I understand the first part (it's not possible), I don't quite get the second part of your comment. Mind to elaborate? Or some good external resources on this?